# if slidetoggle is open show specific background positioin

Tags: jquery, toggle

Any idea how to set the background position so when the tab is closed the background is always 'background-position', '5% 50%' 
and if the tab is open it's background position is always 'background-position', '5% 115%' ?

I'm assuming there needs to be an if(element).is(':hidden') statement somewhere.

Thanks!

```
$('.blue-tab').toggle(function() {  
        var group = $(this).parent('.group-wrap').children('.indi-group');  
            $('.indi-group').not(group).hide(300);
            group.slideToggle(600, function() {
                $(this).parent('.group-wrap').children('.blue-tab').css('background-position', '5% 115%');
            });
    }, function() {
        var group = $(this).parent('.group-wrap').children('.indi-group');
            $('.indi-group').not(group).hide(300);
            group.slideToggle(600, function() {
                $(this).parent('.group-wrap').children('.blue-tab').css('background-position', '5% 50%');
            });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.is(":visible")` - [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)
You can use this to test against if the selected element is visible or hidden.

So you would do something like this:

```
if($('.blue-tab').is(":visible")){
    // Change your BG position to '5% 115%'
    $(this).parent('.group-wrap').children('.blue-tab').css('background-position', '5% 115%');
} else {
    // Its not visible.. so change the position to '5% 50%'
    $(this).parent('.group-wrap').children('.blue-tab').css('background-position', '5% 50%');
}
```

Make sure you call this before you start any animations, if the element is in mid-transition, it will always be vislble `(TRUE)`, despite if its animating in or out.

Comment: If the answer was right, You can mark it as correct by clicking the arrow outline underneath the voting section.